# setContentView() called first or last?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've recently received a question about creating programmatic views. Why do we call setContentView after all the views have been initialised and all parameters have been set?

Simple example:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val l = LinearLayout(this)
    l.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL
    for (i in 0 until 300)
        l.addView(someTextView(i.toString()))
    setContentView(l)
}

fun someTextView(text: String): TextView {
    val t = TextView(this)
    t.text = text
    return t
}
```

vs

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val l = LinearLayout(this)
    setContentView(l)
    l.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL
    for (i in 0 until 300)
        l.addView(someTextView(i.toString()))

}

fun someTextView(text: String): TextView {
    val t = TextView(this)
    t.text = text
    return t
}
```

Is there any efficiency difference between the two? Also in the case of more complex views?

Comment: why don't you use RecyclerView, ListView?

Comment: @EliasFazel I think it's just part of the example, OP is asking (as I understand it) if it makes a difference in calling setContentView before or after all initialization of views, them making 300 is just part of the example (as i understand it)

Answer (score -1):

There is no problem on your code.This is the reason.
-setContentView just do that which is the view that present the interface of an Activity
-First,You create a linearlayout by the ActivityContext.then add alot of view into it.After that you said "Hey Activity,this is your view".And the second just you attach your linearlayout into Activity and after that you add view into it.both are normal and nothing was wrong.
BUT

setContentView is pretty good in real life cause no one will do what you are trying to do.Every Activity,Fragment .. etc need a xml file which indentify what is the layout of it and every view is organization by the design.After that,they can call it view by the id, organize the view just by edit the xml file ( not change alot alot of code).

So.Basicly setContentView just a method to say with the Activity which View is gonna be the interface of it